# matplotlib Circle patch with alpha produces overlap of edge and facecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to matplotlib and python in general and what I'm trying to do is rather basic. However, even after quite some googling time I cannot find a solution for this:

Here is the problem:

I'd like to draw a circle with different color of the border and the face, i.e. set `edgecolor` and `facecolor` differently. I'd also like to have an alpha-channel, i.e. `alpha=0.5`. Now while all of this works fine, the resulting circle does not have a single border color, but 2 borders are drawn. One, the outer, in the color I specified for `edgecolor` and the other in a color I assume to be a combination between the edgecolor and the facecolor.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
point = (1.0, 1.0)
c = plt.Circle(point, 1, facecolor='green', edgecolor='orange', linewidth=15.0, alpha=0.5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(c)
plt.show()
```

And here is an illustration:

[image: circle with 2 border colors]

Ok, this might be a minor thing, but **this 2nd border drives me nuts!**

Am I doing something wrong? Is that just the way it is? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To some extent, yes, this is just the way it is. 
The point is that the edge is literally drawn on the edge of the circle. 
This means that half of the edge width is drawn on top of the face of the circle and the other half outside. If now you set `alpha<1.0` you see, as you concluded correctly, an overlap of the facecolor and the edgecolor.

However, **you can get rid of that 'extra border'**. Below are 2 ways how to do so which one works best for you depends on what exactly you want to do.

**1st Suggestion**:

The simplest, IMHO, is to **only set alpha for the `facecolor`**. This can be done by setting the alpha channel for the `facecolor` directly and omit the `alpha` argument in the call of `Circle`. You can set the alpha-channel with the `colorConverter`:

```
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.axis('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
# Here you set alpha for the faceolor
fc = colorConverter.to_rgba('green', alpha=0.5)
point = (1.0, 1.0)
r = 1.0
lw = 15.0
ec = 'orange'
# NOTE: do not set alpha when calling Circle!
c = plt.Circle(point, r,fc=fc, ec=ec, lw=lw)
ax.add_artist(c)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**2nd Suggestion**

A more elaborated option is to 'wipe' the edge of the circle with a white edge after only plotting the face, then only plot the edge.
With this approach both colours appear with the alpha channel. But note that also in this case any object that lies 'under' the edge will be completely masked by the edge:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

point = (1.0, 1.0)
r = 1.0
alpha = 0.5
lw = 15.0
fc = 'green'
ec = 'orange'
# First only draw the facecolor
c_face = plt.Circle(point, r, alpha=alpha, fc=fc, lw=0.0)
# Draw a non-transparent white edge to wipe the facecolor where they overlap
c_wipe = plt.Circle(point, r, alpha=1.0, ec='white', fc='none', lw=lw)
# Now draw only the edge
c_edge = plt.Circle(point, r, alpha=alpha, fc='none', ec=ec, lw=lw)
circle_patch = PatchCollection([c_face, c_wipe, c_edge], match_original=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.axis('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.add_artist(circle_patch)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/j-i-l/a88720d934b921a9338030a55dced2d1) that deals with this issue following the 2nd suggestion. Simply download the [mod_patch.py](https://gist.github.com/j-i-l/a88720d934b921a9338030a55dced2d1#file-mod_patch-py) file and off you go.

Here is how it can be used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mod_patch import get_Patch
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
c = get_Patch(plt.Circle, (0,0.5), 0.5, facecolor='green', edgecolor='orange', alpha=0.5, lw=15)
ax.add_artist(c)
r = get_Patch(plt.Rectangle, (0.5,0), 0.5, 0.5, facecolor='green', edgecolor='orange', alpha=0.5, lw=15)
ax.add_artist(r)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For completeness, here the definition of `get_Patch`:

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


def get_Patch(a_Patch, *args, **kwargs):
    background_color = kwargs.pop(
        'bgc',
        kwargs.pop('background_color', 'white')
    )
    alpha = kwargs.get('alpha', 1.0)
    patches = []
    lw = kwargs.get('lw', kwargs.get('linewidth', 0.0))
    if alpha < 1.0 and lw:
        color = kwargs.get('c', kwargs.get('color', None))
        fc = kwargs.get('facecolor', kwargs.get('fc', None))
        ec = kwargs.get('edgecolor', kwargs.get('ec', None))
        face_kwargs = dict(kwargs)
        face_kwargs['fc'] = fc if fc is not None else color
        face_kwargs['lw'] = 0.0
        p_face = a_Patch(*args, **face_kwargs)
        patches.append(p_face)
        wipe_kwargs = dict(kwargs)
        wipe_kwargs['fc'] = 'none'
        wipe_kwargs['ec'] = background_color
        wipe_kwargs['alpha'] = 1.0
        p_wipe = a_Patch(*args, **wipe_kwargs)
        patches.append(p_wipe)
        edge_kwargs = dict(kwargs)
        edge_kwargs['fc'] = 'none'
        edge_kwargs['ec'] = ec if ec is not None else color
        p_edge = a_Patch(*args, **edge_kwargs)
        patches.append(p_edge)
    else:
        p_simple = a_Patch(*args, **kwargs)
        patches.append(p_simple)
    return PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
```

Comment: Wow, this was very quick! This is already less disturbing, but now the edgecolor clearly looks different as the `alpha=0.5` version. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Jep there is! Well, sort of. Give me a sec I'm writing in up... :)

Comment: This is perfect! But tell me, **how can someone that is not a matplotlib wizard know these things?!**

Comment: =) Hah, I'm no matplotlib wizard! I agree matplotlib is not the most straight forward thing to use. Personally, I use a little script to create me those extra patches, I'll put it as a gist on github and put the link here.

Comment: Would you mind providing the code inside the answer, instead of linking to it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sure! The answer contains all the code that solves the problem, even in two different ways (1st and 2nd suggestion). The script mentioned deals with the edge-face overlap of matplotlib patches more generally and is not just restricted to Circles. In that sense it is more an extension to the answer, that's why I only linked it. But I don't mind putting the code here. Or maybe I should just move it to the end of the answer?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ok, I moved it to the end. Looks clearer now: 2 ways of solving the problem with complete code example and, as a suggestion, link to gist dealing with edge-face overlap of matplotlib patches more generally.

Comment: I'm refering to the `get_Patch` function, which is not part of the answer here. As one often stumbles upon answers with broken links, I though it to be useful to have it inside the answer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are right! The definition of `get_Patch` is added.